# JavaScript regex for matching any number ending with zero or one occurrence of specific character

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to match a string which has to begin with any number and followed by zero or one occurrence of 'w' or 'm' character. E.g. `123`, `321w` or `231m`

```
'^[0-9]+$' works fine for just the number checking.
```

I guess something along the lines of `[wm]{0,1}` must be added to check for 0 or 1 occurrence of w or m?

Comment: If you downvote, please explain why.

Comment: FYI: you actually created a working solution - `^[0-9]+[wm]{0,1}$`. Hence the downvotes - it was not difficult to check by yourself.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, i did check it, but couldn't make it work.

Comment: Maybe you should explain what did not work? Downvotes can be relieved once you make your question better by adding what you tried and what did not work.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following regex

```
/^\d+[wm]?$/
```

`^` and `$` - anchors for start and end position

`\d+` - match any digit combination

`[wm]?` - match optional `w` or `m` at the end

---

[Regex explanation here.](https://regex101.com/r/tV7eC1/1)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: isn't the question suggesting that starts width and ends with that there is something else in between?

Comment: @Dalorzo, thanks for pointing that out, I meant there will be nothing in between. I changed the question.